# Try except clause adjacent to if statement conflict

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, try-catch

Let me explain the problem with some demo codes:

```
 def my_func:
    if not a:
        #operations A here.
    try:
        #operations B here. 
    except:
        #operations C here.
```

The problem here is that the try-except clause seems to be included into the if statement. Only if "not a" is True, the try-except clause statements would be executed, other wise they would never be executed.

I tried to shrink some indent space before try-except clause as follow:

```
def my_func:
    if not a:
        #operations A here.
try:
    #operations B here. 
except:
    #operations C here.
```

Now everything seems to work as try-except is executed independently with the if statement.

Any explanation is really appreciated.

Comment: The indentation in your sample looks correct. You should show us some real code instead.

Comment: You may have mixed tabs and spaces, leading the interpreter to think the indentations are different. Please try to run the program with `python -tt` and python will probably complain about mixing tabs and spaces. In this case fix the indentation using always spaces instead of tabs. The only thing I can tell for sure is that *if* the problem is not this mixing and *if* the code has indeed the same structure you show, then there must be something else wrong with *your* code so you should consider providing an example that we can run.

Comment: The first block works as expected for me: see http://ideone.com/yLahE2

Comment: @bakuriu Please make your comment as answer. It seems to I did mix tab with whitespace in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed tabs with spaces in your indentation, this lead the interpreter to misinterpret the indentation levels, thinking that the `try` was one level higher:

```
>>> if True:
...     if True:   # indentation with 4 spaces. Any number will do
...     a = 1      # indentation with a tab. Equals two indents with spaces
...     else:      # indentation with 4 spaces
...     a = 2
... 
>>> a   # as if the "a = 1" was inside the second if
1
```

To check whether this is the problem launch the program via `python -tt` which raises an error if it finds mixed tabs and spaces. Also note that when using python3 it *automatically* runs with the `-tt` option, not allowing mixing tabs and spaces.